# Chrome Developer Tools: How to Read the Network Panel?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, network-protocols

I am trying to make sense of the Chrome Developer Tools when I run performence tests on my websites. If you select Network on the tools meny it will look like this:

[image]

Then if I select the performance file I will have this information:

[image]

My question is this:

1. *What is the meaning of DNS Lookup, Connecting, Sending, Waiting and Receving? What is happening between the server, network and browser at each stage?*
2. *On the first image, the red line reads "Load event fired" and the blue one reads "DOMContent event fired". What is the meaning of this and why is it the DOMContent event is fired after all the content has been loaded?*

Comment: Here is a description by Google:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a good fit for SO as this is a network question more than a programming question but I'll answer the parts I can...

**DNS Lookup**

When you connect to a website, it has to look up the IP from the DNS. For example, your computer will contact a DNS asking if it knows where "google.com" is. If it does, it'll give you an IP. If it doesn't, it'll either give you the IP of another DNS or it will contact that DNS itself (I'm not sure which implementation applies where) until eventually you end up with the IP of the host you're looking for.

**Connecting**

Time it takes to connect with that IP. I'm not sure of the details here.

**Sending**

After connecting, you send the request to the server. It can be a request to view a page or submit data or anything.

**Waiting**

After sending your request, you wait for the server to respond to it. It can be busy or might take a while to process whatever you requested.

**Receiving**

Once the server has processed your request, it'll send data back to you.

Comment: So basically, the red line in the first image marks when the file has been loaded from the network, and the blue line marks when this content has been parsed by the browser?

Comment: Is the red line at 311ms? If so, then that's when the content has been received from the server. Then I guess Chrome does it's stuff to load the page into your browser and then the DOM event stuff is fired. I'm honestly not sure, but the browser has to load the page before anything with the DOM can happen.

Answer (score 38):

Answering part II:

**The Blue line (DOM content loaded event):** 
It happens when the browser finished parsing the main document.
**The Red line (Load event):** 
It happens when the browser finished retrieving all the resources required by the main document.
**After the red line:** Here you will see loading of asynchronous and cached resources required by the main document and by other resources.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for :-)